# Фильтр post_link не работает. Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

```
function append_query_string($url, $post, $leavename) {
    if ($post->post_type == 'post') {
        $url = add_query_arg('foo', 'bar', $url);
    }

    return $url;
}

add_filter('post_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 3);
```

Пример с документации, в файле functions.php размещен код. Он не срабатывает. term_link фильтр работает.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, как вы определяете срабатывание фильтра?

Comment: @tutankhamun, у меня вызывается get_permalink множество раз, я перед get_permalink() делал print_r и оно выводило мне. А в конце функции get_permalink() есть применение этого фильтра.

Comment: Фильтр сразатывает в конце вызова функции `get_permalink()`. Может у вас так построена тема, что эта функция не вызывается?

Comment: @tutankhamun, Эта функция вызывается, ну может она каким то образом переопределена? Но это вряд ли , я делал ReflectionMethod и смотрел имя файла и номер строки. Показывает тот файл в wp-includes.

Comment: в `get_permalink()` есть несколько возвратов без применения фильтров. Посмотрите там, может до фильтра и правда не доходит

Comment: @tutankhamun, post_type_link вот такой срабатывает, все верно вы говорите.

Comment: @tutankhamun если можете, преобразуйте в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фильтр `post_link` срабатывает в конце вызова функции `get_permalink()`. Однако у этой функции есть еще 4 возможных вариантов возврата, в зависимости от срабатывания условий в вот этом участке кода:

```
if ( empty($post->ID) )
    return false;

if ( $post->post_type == 'page' )
    return get_page_link($post, $leavename, $sample);
elseif ( $post->post_type == 'attachment' )
    return get_attachment_link( $post, $leavename );
elseif ( in_array($post->post_type, get_post_types( array('_builtin' => false) ) ) )
    return get_post_permalink($post, $leavename, $sample);
```

Наверное, в вашем случае, до применения указанного фильтра дело не доходит.

Answer (score -2):

Если данная функция из примера прописана у вас внутри класса, то попробуйте этот вариант

```
function append_query_string($url, $post, $leavename) {
    if ($post->post_type == 'post') {
        $url = add_query_arg('foo', 'bar', $url);
    }

    return $url;
}

add_filter('post_link', array($this, 'append_query_string'), 10, 3);
```

Comment: Не работает так

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, а как вы проверяете работоспособность post_link?

Comment: Нет бы поправили, только минусовать и могут )

Comment: @Visman у меня не работает, я в functions.php пишу, а так у меня вызывается get_permailnk , где применяется этот фильтр.

Comment: Она не внутри класса.

Comment: @NickVolynkin тут невозможно что-либо исправить. Поясню: `$this` не определена вне методов класса, потому и не работает. В тоже время, вызов функции в контексте `$this` - это единственное отличие от кода в вопросе. Одним словом -- нужен другой ответ :) Потому и минусуют.